# Time Lag for Market Inefficiency

Tags: research

I recalled reading a academic paper that studied how long a market exploitation took to get priced into the market.

I am trying to find that article. I remember it stating that the market priced in the exploitation on average around 30 days.

Comment: Hi user7954, welcome to Quant.SE! I removed the apology, the question seems to be on-topic to me and at least two community members ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question. I was actually looking for was this. CharlesM, your answer was not bad as well. Appreciate the reply.

**Does Academic Research Destroy Stock Return Predictability?**

[Does Academic Research Destroy Stock Return Predictability?](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2156623)

Answer (score 1):

By market exploitation ... not so sure if I understand what you are saying but I suggest this [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1787215). It is on the slow information diffusion where for some portfolio of stocks it can take up to 30 days if not more for the information to get impounded into the stock prices.